# strange issue with facebook sharer on different domains

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share pages of a website on Facebook using the following Facebook sharer link:

```
http://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http:/<link of the page>
```

On page load I am setting the following meta tags:

```
<meta property='og:title' />
<meta property='og:image' />
<meta property='og:url' />
<meta property='og:description' />
<meta property='og:site_name' />
```

When I am trying to share a page from my website, on the `Facebook sharer page` before posting the link on my timeline, the `og` tags are read correctly and the `title`, `image`, `site_name` are picked up and the preview is working fine but when I click on `Post to Facebook` button and check the post on my Facebook timeline, the `title` and `image` for some reason are not displayed, it shows only the website name. I have implemented the same `og` tags on an another website with a different domain and there it works totally fine without any issue, the title and image are displayed properly on my timeline without any problems.

At this point I am assuming that there maybe some issue with the domain of the website and its somehow cached on Facebook which is causing some kind of problem as the same implementation is working correctly on another domain. How can I fix this issue?

Edit: I am trying to share the following link:

http://sawalefnewsletter.com/autumn-2016/gallery/26?img=10

Edit 2: I am also sharing the following link from another domain which is working perfectly fine:

http://alhabtoorpoloresortandclub.com/album/46/al-habtoor-training-jumping-show?img=461

Comment: So what URL are you trying to share?

Comment: @WizKid I am trying to share: http://sawalefnewsletter.com/autumn-2016/gallery/26?img=10

Comment: According to the debugger you are redirecting to an error page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=sawalefnewsletter.com%2Fautumn-2016%2Fgallery%2F26%3Fimg%3D10

Comment: @WizKid I have checked with another link using the debugger and the preview is working but I cannot see the image and title again after I post it on my timeline https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsawalefnewsletter.com%2Fautumn-2016%2Fgallery%2F26%3Fimg%3D9

Comment: That one is showing errors for me too:  
Input URL arrow-right http://sawalefnewsletter.com/autumn-2016/gallery/26?img=9
og:url Meta Tag arrow-right http://sawalefnewsletter.com/gallery/26?img=9
302 HTTP Redirect arrow-right http://sawalefnewsletter.com/Error/General?aspxerrorpath=/gallery/26

Comment: @WizKid I have removed the `query string` parameter `img` and changed the URL structure of the website link and now share is working fine https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsawalefnewsletter.com%2Fautumn-2016%2Fgallery%2F26%2Fimg%2F8 ...but I am still using `query string` parameter on the other website link I have mentioned in the question and there the share is working fine, what could be the reason? maybe there is some problem with query string being present in the share URL?

Comment: No idea. We can't know what you are doing different.